# ReactJS - /path/:id redirects with string :id instead of id value

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I am writing redirect rule with react-router. Defined my  **route**  as follows:

```
{
  path: '/inputs',
  component: InputsContainer,
  label: 'Inputs',
  icon: 'fal fa-mobile',
  menu: false,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/inputs',
      component: () => <Redirect to="/om/inputs" />,
      index: true,
      exact: true
    },
    {
      path: '/inputs/:id',
      component: (location) => <Redirect exact from="/inputs/:id" to={`/om/orders/:id`} />,
      label: "Order Details",
      menu: false
    },
    notFoundRoute
  ]
}
```

Here, /inputs redirects to /om/inputs without any issue. But  **/inputs/23 getting redirected to /om/input/:id**

What I am missing here? I want this to be redirected to  **/om/inputs/23**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give a url instead of path to `Redirect`. Since you are using the render prop pattern, you can get it using `match.params.id` where `match` is obtained from the callback function param. Make sure you use `render` instead of `Component` as a prop to Route

```
{
  path: '/inputs',
  component: InputsContainer,
  label: 'Inputs',
  icon: 'fal fa-mobile',
  menu: false,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/inputs',
      render: () => <Redirect to="/om/inputs" />,
      index: true,
      exact: true
    },
    {
      path: '/inputs/:id',
      render: ({match}) => <Redirect exact from="/inputs/:id" to={`/om/orders/${match.params.id}`} />,
      label: "Order Details",
      menu: false
    },
    notFoundRoute
  ]
}
```

Comment: The documentation here https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect/from-string makes it more understandable and also other ways to do it.